# extracting value from an array in splunk

Tags: splunk, rex

I have a field testing.name{}.nameParts.value that I am trying to evaluate and split the value into 3 columns, firstname, middlename, and surname

The data within the field looks as such

```
testing.name{}.nameParts: [
           { 
             type: GivenName
             value:John
           }
           {
             type: GivenName
             value: X
           }
           {
             type: Surname
             value: Doe
           }
    ]
```

Here is my code - but I can't get it to work as the payload structure is a bit tricky to transpose - the firstname and middlename are both represented as GivenName within the event payload

```
| spath input="testing.name{}.nameParts{}" output=names
| mvexpand names
| eval type = names.type, value = names.value
| eval firstname=if(type=="GivenName", value, null()), middlename=if(type=="GivenName" AND isnull(firstname), value, null()), surname=if(type=="Surname", value, null())
| stats values(firstname) as firstname, values(middlename) as middlename, values(surname) as surname
```

I also Tried this

```
| rex field=testing.name{}.nameParts{}.value "\btype:\s*(?<type>[^\s]+)\s*value:\s*(?<value>[^\s]+)"
| eval FirstName = if(type=="GivenName", value,null()), MiddleName = if(type=="GivenName", value,null()), Lastname = if(type=="Surname", value, null())
| stats values(GivenName) as FirstName, values(MiddleName) as MiddleName, values(LastName) as LastName
```

Comment: Have you tried the `spath` command?  Please share a sanitized raw event we can test with.

Comment: @RichG I have added the command in the descriptions

Answer (score 1):

Try the following run anywhere SPL:

```
| makeresults 
| eval _raw="
{
    \"testing\": {
        \"name\": [{
                \"nameParts\": [{
                        \"type\": \"GivenName\",
                        \"value\": \"John David\"
                    }, {
                        \"type\": \"GivenName\",
                        \"value\": \"X Y\"
                    }, {
                        \"type\": \"Surname\",
                        \"value\": \"Doe\"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}

"
| spath input=_raw path=testing.name{}.nameParts{}.value output=firstname
| spath input=_raw path=testing.name{}.nameParts{}.type output=lastname

| eval zipNames=mvzip(firstname,lastname)
| mvexpand zipNames
| rex field=zipNames "^(?<Firstname>\w+)(?:\h+(?<Middlename>\w+))?,(?<Lastname>[^,]+)$"
| table Firstname Middlename Lastname
```